# Display errors on fields with global validation

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to implement a global validation on a form and change the color of some inputs according to this validation.

I have three fields. Two fields are required only if the value of the first field is 'test'.

Here is what I implemented:

```
function typeValidator(form: FormGroup) {
  const type = form.controls['field1'].value;
  if (type === 'test') {
    const field2 = form.controls['field2'].value;
    const field3 = form.controls['field3'].value;
    return (!field2 || !field3) ? { requiredIf: true } : null;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Regarding the HTML:

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-select formControlName="field1" placeholder="Field1">
    <mat-option value="test">Test</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="other">Other</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-select formControlName="field2" placeholder="Field2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of elements" [value]="element.id">{{element.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Validation works fine but I wanted to change the color to orange for `field2` when I have a validation error of type `requiredIf` for the form.

Thanks for your help.
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Add `typeValidator` as a custom validator to the fields you want.  You can check if a form control have a custom error by `myFormControl.hasError('myError')`  That conditional can be used in class statements to add / remove a class based on the error state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the global  validation error is set on the form group itself... Is the error set when the type validator is called? Could you add some sample code for your approach? Thanks!

Comment: With `FormGroup` you can just use the same method `myFormGroup.hasError('myError')` .  If your `typeValidator` returns `requiredIf: true` then it sets the error for the `FormGroup`.  Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3wqeo